# How can I subset an array based off of binary column values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I ran a binary classification using XGBoost and SVM as models.  I want to analyze how the models did individually vs. in combination.

I have an ndarray with shape=(4500,5).

The column structure is:

[y, 0_0, 1_0, 0_1, 1_1]

- y: Actual value, 0 or 1
- 0_0: Both XGB and SVM predict 0
- 1_0: XGB predicts 1, SVM predicts 0
- 0_1: XGB predicts 0, SVM predicts 1
- 1_1: Both XGB and SVM predict 1

So for each row, only one of columns 2-5 contain the value 1.

How can I grab 4 subsets based on columns 2-5?  More familiar with this in R, not sure how the syntax is in Python.

And side question, is there an equivalent to precision/recall that has a multiple categories for this case of combined models?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is something like

```py
subset00=data[data[:,1]==1]
subset10=data[data[:,2]==1]
subset01=data[data[:,3]==1]
subset11=data[data[:,4]==1]
```

Not 100% sure, because your question is not 100% clear and lacks an example.

As for the precision/recall thing, there again, you need to make clear what you are thinking of with an example. It is not clear for me what it would mean to compute precision/recall not on a prediction, but on a set of different predictions (but, anyway, SO rules are "only one question per question". Plus, this 2nd question is more theoretical than coding, and SO is about coding. You would have better chance to find an answer to this question on [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com))